# Any suggestions as to how I could improve this question?

Tags: support

I asked [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/61357/23094) a while back which I thought was a fairly simple reference request for what must be quite a common pool of studies (though I'd not managed to find any, hence the question). I've not had any answers, which seemed odd given the above. Is there anything about the question which confuses what I'm asking for or some tags I'm missing which might help me get some better results?

Comment: Actually I've been looking at some papers on this, as a colleague of mine was working on this, but unfortunately I think the work wasn't published. It's kind of a difficult subject. I think, from memory, that low-dose ionizing radiation has a hormetic effect. But honestly, I don't know. I think the question is good and it was upvoted (including by me).

Comment: From a brief look, all of those papers are review papers. A search on Google Scholar for "hormesis" brings up some 20,000 results, some of which are primary papers. I would look at those, and then look at the papers that cite those. If someone was refuting a result they would almost certainly cite the result they are refuting.

Comment: Note also that there is a different standard for review/opinion papers versus basic science. People can make fairly wild claims in an opinion piece, even in a reputable journal, in some cases. That's sort of the point: to stir some controversy and interest, and to encourage people to publish on the issue in the future. My suspicion, though I don't know the field, is that Calabrese has shown this effect for some substances, but he wants to extrapolate it to *all* substances, and while his specific results may be reasonable, the extrapolation maybe is considered a bit of quackery.

Comment: The other problem is the seeminig connection with homeopathy, which is 100% discredited. It may be that works that critique these types of studies don't bother to use the terminology invented by Calabrese. Again, however, this isn't my field and I don't know how he is regarded. Note that just holding a professorship does not allow someone to speak for all the science in their field: that's one of the magics of tenure.

Comment: Hmm sorry for all the comments, as I jump around here I get some new insights. Like the first link you gave on your question: he's talking about U-shaped dose-response curves. I've actually never heard the term hormesis before, but the things he is talking about and making sound really novel are not novel at all there. It's less about "low doses being beneficial" and simply that there is not a linear relationship between dose and effect. That's the sort of thing that's just super obvious in biology.

Comment: It might be that he's running with some things that are really obvious and trying to make a big deal out of them like there is some conspiracy to ignore these effects, when there isn't, and every serious biologist and physician uses that knowledge all the time. Kind of reminds me of a previous discussion we had here at Biology.SE about someone who "discovered" allostasis and wrote papers about everyone talking about homeostasis is wrong...the problem is everyone else was using the term homeostasis to include what he called "allostasis': there was no conspiracy or discovery.

Comment: @AliceD  I'd be interested to see the papers if they ever get published. I was hoping, in asking this on Meta, that I'd missed some tag or something that might lead me to a textbook answer. Seeing as the whole of toxicology for the the entire Western world is based on the Linear No Threshold model, I presumed there'd be a simple reference that someone could point to. It's a little worrying if there isn't.

Comment: @Bryan It's obvious that each substance may vary, but that's not the way it's treated in toxicology, it's treated as universally having a LNT dose-response relationship (at least that's what Calabrese seems to be saying). Calabrese extrapolates from a few hundred substances to suggest *all* substances **could** have a u-shaped dose-response curves. If that is considered "quackery", then why would the same be done with the LNT model from what sounds like even fewer proven relationships? Hence my expectation of some simple textbook answer.

Comment: It may be 'super-obvious' in biology that u-shaped curves exist for substances, but the point that Calabrese is making is that the upward bit of the 'u' means it is actually good for you, i.e. we would be doing harm by eliminating it. Now if it's so 'super-obvious' that u-shaped curves exist, and harm would be done by ignoring them, then why is every single toxin presumed to have a LNT dose-response, without exception? That's the bit of all this that I'm struggling to comprehend.

Comment: Got it - this seems to be something specific to toxicology, rather than biology in general, and has more to do with public policy than science per se. Note that the community here is fairly small - I don't think we have a resident toxicologist, so there just might not be anybody with the right expertise to see your question as a simple one. I had to do a lot of reading to try to understand the issue and what exactly you were asking.

Comment: The wikipedia page on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_no-threshold_model links to several studies on both sides of the issue for radiation in particular.

Comment: This editorial in Science: http://science.sciencemag.org/content/302/5644/376/tab-pdf seems to be a fairly neutral assessment, though it's also almost 15 years old.